# How to write regex to match equal pairs of delimiters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, date

I have different dates like this:

```
DD-MM-YY
DD.MM.YYYY
YYYY/MM/DD
```

But the delimiter in the dates could be a dash `-` or a dot `.` or forward slash `/`.

I have tried regex that works but I need to check if date is entered with non-matching delimiters like this `DD-MM/YY` then it should be invalid because the 1st delimiter is `-` and 2nd one is `/`.

My attempt so far:

```
/^\d\d?\d?\d?[-\/.]\d?\d[-\/.]\d\d?\d?\d?$/.test(userDate)
```

How can I check if the 2nd delimiter is same as 1st delimiter?

Comment: Use back references, e.g. `([./-])` for the first delimiter and `\1` for the second.

Comment: do you also expect the regex to validate that `DD` is 1-31 and `MM` is 1-12 ?

Comment: @pretzelhammer No

Comment: @kittu this isn't a very useful validation, in that case. Not that you should be doing validation for correct *dates* in regex, however, you can at least check if what's entered *could* be a date. Right now, this allows something like `6-6-6` to be entered. The only point of the validation is to have consistent delimiters but the numbers between the delimiters may never really be used to denote a coherent date. If I were to do a validation in regex, I'd check if it fits `\d\d-\d\d-\d\d` or `\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d` or `\d\d\d\d/\d\d/\d\d`. At least it seems like a date, then.

Comment: Something, like `2020/55/2020` will pass the check. I'd say, consistent delimiters is the least of your concerns with current approach.

Comment: @VLAZ Those other validations are taken care of. I just need to validate the above back reference checks

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Those validations are happening in other code base. I just need to check consistent delimiters

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I completely agree. I'd just use a date library and feed it the formats I expect. It should take care of everything for me - delimiters, parsing, validation, whatever. No need to reinvent the wheel here. The only reason to use regex should be to check for conforming formats, *then* extract the suspected days, months, years and try to fit them into a `Date` object and see if the result is coherent. Then possibly try variations, in case it's `DD/MM` or `MM/DD` for example. However, that and more is already covered by a date library.

Comment: @kittu if you *only* want consistent delimiters, then you should just match any non-digits and then see if all those characters are the same. Done.

Comment: Doing some kind of multi-stage validations separately doesn't seem to make sense, while could be done easily together. If you need to check up delimiters only, something as simple as [`\d{2}(\d{2})?([.\-\/])\d{2}\2\d{2}(\d{2})?`](https://regex101.com/r/RxCR1B/1) will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example using `\d` to capture digits, `([-\/.])` to capture the first delimiter, and a regex [backreference](https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences) `\1` to re-capture the same delimiter as in the first capture group:

```js
function testUserDate(userDate) {
  let regex = /^\d{1,4}([-\/.])\d{1,2}\1\d{1,4}$/;
  return regex.test(userDate);
}

console.log(testUserDate("2007-11-12")); // true
console.log(testUserDate("2007.11.12")); // true
console.log(testUserDate("2007/11/12")); // true
console.log(testUserDate("2007/11-12")); // false
console.log(testUserDate("2007.11/12")); // false
console.log(testUserDate("12-12-2007")); // true
console.log(testUserDate("12/12/2007")); // true
console.log(testUserDate("12.12.2007")); // true
console.log(testUserDate("12/12-2007")); // false
console.log(testUserDate("12-12.2007")); // false
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird yup, but OP stated in the comments that they were only interested in using the regex to match a pair of equal delimiters, and they already had separate validation code to check the day, month, and year ranges.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [date like pattern](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) but note that this would only narrow down the possible matches and does not validate a date itself.

To match the variants listed in the question, you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`

To match the consistent delimiters, you could make use of a capturing group `([-/.])` and a backreference `\1` or `\2` to that group

If you don't want to restrict the year to 19 or 20 you could change `(?:19|20)` to `\d{2}`

```
^(?:(?:19|20)\d\d([-/.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\1(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-/.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(?:19|20)(?:\d\d)?)$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `(?:19|20)\d\d` Match either 19 or 20 and 2 digits
  - `([-/.])` Match 1 of the listed using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and capture in **group 1**
  - `(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\1` Month part with optional 0 and backreference to group 1 `\1`
  - `(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` Day part with optional 0
  - `|` Or
  - *This part will match ending with a year with 2 optional digits for the year part*
  - `(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-/.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(?:19|20)(?:\d\d)?`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c03lyu/1)

Comment: Actually I will look into it. Seems it might help

Comment: What is `1[012] ? I didn't get it

Comment: That is the month 10, 11 or 12. This is an alternation `(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])` which matches an optional zero and a digit 1-9 for the first 9 months, or you match 10, 11 or 12. That mechanism is also used for the days.

Comment: what if I  type 1012 as month, it will be valid right?

Comment: @kittu That would not be valid https://regex101.com/r/KtkG3u/1 I have added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: How does day `11` matches in `(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` ? I see only 01-09 and then 12

Comment: The character class `[12]` matches 1 or 2. The character class `[0-9]` matches a digit from 0 till 9.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to require the delimiters to be consistent, you could use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). `^(19|20)\d\d([- /.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$` will match 1999-01-01 but not 1999/01-01.